# UTF8 filenames and shell utilities

Tags: command-line, unicode

Try the next commands from the terminal:

```
touch á.txt
$ ls
á.txt

find .  -name á.txt -print
```

prints nothing.

My Terminal.app settings are utf8 - see here:

[image]

**The question: How to achieve to work transprarently (Finder + command line) with UNICODE filenames?**

I understand than behind the scene is the different unicode normalization, so:

```
$ echo á.txt | od -bc
0000000   303 241 056 164 170 164 012                                    
           á  **   .   t   x   t  \n
```

and when

```
$touch á.txt
$ ls *.txt
á.txt

$ ls *.txt | od -bc
0000000   141 314 201 056 164 170 164 012                                
           a   ́     **   .   t   x   t  \n
```

**but WHAT IS THE SOLUTION?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, characters like á are stored or shown in decomposed form (LATIN SMALL LETTER A + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT) even though most keyboard layouts insert characters in composed form (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE).

The format is a variant of NFD where some ranges of characters are not decomposed. See [Text Encodings in VFS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1173/_index.html):

> Important: The terms used in this Q&A, precomposed and decomposed, roughly correspond to Unicode Normal Forms C and D, respectively. However, most volume formats do not follow the exact specification for these normal forms. For example, HFS Plus (Mac OS Extended) uses a variant of Normal Form D in which U+2000 through U+2FFF, U+F900 through U+FAFF, and U+2F800 through U+2FAFF are not decomposed (this avoids problems with round trip conversions from old Mac text encodings).

You can convert text to the decomposed format with `iconv -t utf-8-mac`:

```
$ touch á
$ ls | tr -d '\n' | xxd -p
61cc81
$ printf á | xxd -p
c3a1
$ find . -name á
$ find . -name $(iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac <<< á)
./á
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot (in 13.3) put decomposed text in a filename (to avoid rewriting scripts).  Terminal (or `mv`) automatically converts them to composed.

Comment: @WGroleau OK. The question is 9 years old. :D

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to wait for [macOS 13.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-13_4-release-notes) which is said to fix a bug relating to composed normalization.

Comment: The problem probably fixed in 13.4 is different from the one here. The example from the question (with `á.txt`) works for me on 13.3.