# XQuartz, utf-8 and filenames

Tags: macos, file, xquartz, utf-8

This is a question in the continuation of this one:
[UTF8 filenames and shell utilities](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/95483/22003):
the nightmare of utf-8 and filenames is….

How to avoid this confusion with most notably the `ls` command on filnames created in the following way:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ touch á
$ touch a´
$
```

The first file is created by typing <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, the second one by typing <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Within an `xterm` window I get:

```
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 hal  admin   136 Nov 11 15:52 .
drwxr-x---  7 hal  admin  4386 Nov 11 14:25 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 hal  admin     0 Nov 11 15:52 a´
-rw-r--r--  1 hal  admin     0 Nov 11 15:48 a´
$
```

Which is wrong.

Within a `Terminal` window I get:

```
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 hal  admin   136 Nov 11 15:52 .
drwxr-x---  7 hal  admin  4386 Nov 11 14:25 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 hal  admin     0 Nov 11 15:52 a´
-rw-r--r--  1 hal  admin     0 Nov 11 15:48 á
$
```

Which is right.

The result is the same whichever shell I use: `bash` or `zsh`.

---

What `xterm` or `XQuartz` setting will avoid these 2 filenames to falsely look the same?

---

This problem doesn't exist on Mavericks (MacOS X 10.9).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally sorted with the help of this post:

- http://lists.apple.com/archives/x11-users/2008/Mar/msg00202.html

In summary, go here:

- http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCEnvironment/

Download the preference pane, and add this entry:

```
Key=LANG Value=en_GB.UTF-8
```

I had already added this to my .bashrc and my .profile with no result. But I think XQuartz doesn't launch within that environment, so it never sees it until it is too late.

Comment: First part of your proposal is not relevant. As you may have noticed from the output of the `echo $LANG`, I'm in a fully utf-8 mode up to the shell level.

Comment: 1st URL is dead, 2nd one doesn't seem to be of any help.

Answer (score -1):

I am having a similar issues (related to R documentation), which boil down to the same thing.

From an XQuartz window, if you right click (or CTRL r-click) to get to the VT fonts menu, then select UTF8-fonts and UTF8-encoding, this will probably fix your problem.

However, I have not yet found a way to configure these by default, although I have found this:

```
$ appres XTerm | grep UTF
*fontMenu*utf8-mode*Label:      UTF-8 Encoding
*fontMenu*utf8-fonts*Label:     UTF-8 Fonts
*fontMenu*utf8-title*Label:     UTF-8 Titles
```

I took a wild stab in the dark and added this to my .Xdefaults:

```
xterm*utf8-mode: 1
xterm*utf8-fonts: 1
```

Unsuprisingly this did not work, since these 2 resources don't exist.
I'm still looking for a way to turn it on by default.

Comment: Okay, finally sorted with the help of this post:

Comment: Since you don't really bring any sort of solution to the original problem, I'd suggest you to put this within comments:
"Here is what I tested and failed"
and not within an answer.