# Getting on beta and getting off again

Tags: beta-seed-program

I'm retired and no longer write code unless desperate. :-)  (Been nine years, and I'm surely rusty!)  Therefore I prefer not to install beta O.S.  But now, there’s a bug in 13.3 and 13.3.1 that is probably minor for most people, but [major for me](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457985/really-weird-bug-in-13-3).

Rather than rewrite all my affected scripts, after I install the 13.4 beta, when it becomes "release," how would I get back to my non-beta state?

I know I can restore 13.3 from backup, update, and pull account files with Migration Assistant, but I assume there’s a better way …

A [couple of past options](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231396/how-to-move-from-beta-to-stable-releases-of-os-x) are apparently deprecated or not even available.

I could [convert the filenames](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/utf8-filenames-and-shell-utilities) (and convert back) but that’s quite inconvenient as well.  Correction: `mv (composed) (uncomposed)` actually leaves the filename unchanged with nothing to stderr.

Comment: @Allan, probably not, since one answer is (apparently) no longer available, and the other is deprecated.  Plus, having to enroll and unenroll adds to the inconvenience.  I'm going to look into just converting filenames as in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/utf8-filenames-and-shell-utilities

Comment: The link in the dupe is still current.  I’m not certain as to what you’re referring to as deprecated. I can’t speak to the inconvenience factor as the process seems to be what it is and no way to circumvent it.

Comment: The question was current for El Capitán, but comments on the answers say one is deprecated and the other is not possible.

Comment: If you are part of the beta program, you are not *forced* to install all the beta releases, so you can also just skip them if you are not interested. Anyway, Apple published an [FAQ about the Beta Program](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/faq), I consider this the first place to look for answers on questions about it. Actually, the link is also in the question you considered to be outdated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Beta Program, then in System Settings > General > Software Updates, there are options to 'restore defaults' or otherwise remove yourself from Beta Programs.

The options may vary, depending on which update of Ventura you're on. See https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll for details.

Comment: I'm probably going to go for it as the lesser of two evils (rewriting all my affected scripts being the greater evil).  To answer my own follow-up question, as if this month, yes, I do have to join: https://9to5mac.com/2023/04/11/new-method-installing-beta-macos-watchos/

Comment: Well, that was a big mistake.  13.4 beta is buggier than any Windows I have ever seen.  And Apple says the way to get out of it is to erase the disk and do a full install.